# Execution Context Stack. Violation of the LIFO order using Generator Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The specifications [says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-execution-contexts) that the LIFO order of the Running Execution Context transitions in the Execution Context Stack may be violated by some ECMAScript featues:

> Transition of the running execution context status among execution
>   contexts usually occurs in stack-like last-in/first-out manner.
>   However, some ECMAScript features require non-LIFO transitions of the
>   running execution context.

However the specification doesn't explicitly tell by which exactly.

I've read that the violation may occure when using the Generator Functions. But I absolutely don't understand **why**. Morover I couldn't have been able to find any mentions of this in the [25.3.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#table-56) section of the specification.

```
function *gen() {
    yield 1;
    return 2;
}

let g = new gen();

console.log(g.next().value);

// some other operations

console.log(g.next().value);
```

As far as I understand the lifecycle of the Execution Context Stack in the exmple above may look as follows:

```
EC(global)

->

EC(gen1)
EC(global)

->

EC(global)

->

EC(gen2)
EC(global)

->

EC(global)
```

So I don't see any LIFO violations here.

May be Generator Functions don't even lead to such violation? Or, may be, I misread the specification. Anyways, could you please explain what's going on with the Execution Context Stack when using generators? And how (and why) does LIFO order of the Running Execution Context transitions violates?

Comment: I actually dont know any case, where the execution order is not LIFO

Comment: @JonasW. well, but why does the spec says that there're some feaatures that **require** non-LIFO transitions of the REC then?

Comment: One could argue that the Generators Exection context keeps existing after `yield` returned from it, but this is rather a terminology thing

Comment: @JonasW. Of course, I *do* speak of terminoligy aspects here. And yeah, exectly mention of this moment that the Execution Context keeps existing I couldn't have been able to find in the specification though. But even if it actually does, then where's the violation again? New Execution Contexts keep spawing above this suspended Execution Context of the generator, don't they?

Comment: I dont think so. When we call a function, the current EC is halted, a new EC for the function is created and executed, then when the function `return`s the functions EC is destroyed, and the halted EC is popped from the stack and continues its execution. Now when we take a generator, the generator fucntions EC can `yield` multiple times, that means every `yield` halts the generators EC then it pops the calling EC from the stack, continues with it, and may somewhen resumes to its execution. However thats just guessing, im not a grammar expert.

Comment: @JonasW I think that it's not quite right though. Take a look at the 25.3.3.5's 6th step. The EC of the generator gets *removed* on the `yield`, but not just halted. If I understand this correct, of course. Nevetheless, I think that the best option right now is to wait for someone who can give exact answer to my question, and not to make us guess of what's going on.

Comment: Nope, if you do `yield* generator` the generators EC will be removed afterwards, wich is logical as the generator definetly ended its execution (thats 25.3.3.5). For a standard `yield`, the EC gets stored in [[GeneratorContext]] until the generator is called the next time